# Join 2 tables and nested select(s) to count in diff columns from same field

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I tried to look for hours without success...

My problem is the following: I need to join 2 tables, let's say `Persons` and `Documents`. In the `Documents` table, I have a column `document_type` which contains diff types of documents (i.e. passport, driving license). Each person can have multiple times the same document (i.e. 2 times the passport).

I would like to achieve this result with a single complex query: showing only 1 row each `Person` and one column for each `document_type` which shows the count() of each document type.

```
PERSON|PASSPORT|DRIVING_LICENCE|SCHOOL_BADGE
Mark  |2       |1              |0
Lisa  |1       |0              |1
```

But I simply cannot. The only thing I am achieving is to get something like one Person only and the count of all documents for that document type, like:

```
PERSON|PASSPORT

Mark  |4
```

This is the simple schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `Persons` 
(
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `person` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) 

CREATE TABLE `Documents` 
(
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `project_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `document_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `document_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) 

SELECT 
    p.person,
    COUNT(d.document_type) AS passport
FROM
    Persons p 
LEFT JOIN 
    Documents d ON p.id = d.person_id
WHERE
    d.document_type = 'passport'
```

The expected result is:

```
PERSON|PASSPORT|DRIVING_LICENCE|SCHOOL_BADGE
Mark  |2       |1              |0
Lisa  |1       |0              |1
```

But I have no idea how to replicate the above query for all document type and merge everything in one single big query.

I'm freaking out! Could you please help me? Thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select p.person,
       sum(case when d.document_type = 'passport' then 1 else 0 end) as num_passport,    
       sum(case when d.document_type = 'driving license' then 1 else 0 end) as num_driving_license,
       sum(case when d.document_type = 'school badge' then 1 else 0 end) as num_school_badge
from Persons p left join
     Documents d 
     on p.id = d.person_id
group by p.person;
```

In MySQL, you an shorten this to:

```
select p.person,
       sum(d.document_type = 'passport') as num_passport,    
       sum(d.document_type = 'driving license') as num_driving_license,
       sum(d.document_type = 'school badge') as num_school_badge
from Persons p left join
     Documents d 
     on p.id = d.person_id
group by p.person;
```

Comment: This is awesome and perfectly working! Thanks a ton! This will save me from doing several nested 'for' in PHP and leverage the db server instead! Thanks again